# Problems with binding popover to dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Currently my websites consists of multiple pages, which are loaded dynamically. On certain pages there are some buttons which I would like to have popovers. I read some documentation and stackoverflow answers on popovers and dynamic content. However, I can't seem to get it working. Below you'll find my code:

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var popOverSettings = {
        trigger: "click",
        placement: 'bottom',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        //content:" <div style='color:red'>This is your div content</div>"
        content: function () {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }

    };
    $('div').on('DOMNodeInserted', function () {
        $(".pop-function").popover(popOverSettings).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    //$(event.target).find('button[rel=popover]').popover(popOverSettings);
    });
    try {
        $("button[rel=popover]").popover(popOverSettings).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } catch (err) {}
});
```

**The HTML button**

```
<button class="pop-function" rel="popover">Button</button>
```